# Undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a project but whenever i trying to `create grade` for `Class student` using `current_user.grade.create()` or `current_user.create_grade()` getting an error "undefined method create for nil class"

My code is as follows.

Student.rb

```
class Student < User

  has_one :user_grade , dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_one :grade , through: :user_grade

end
```

Grade.rb

```
class Grade < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :user_grades, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :admins, through: :user_grades

  has_many :teachers, through: :user_grades

  has_many :students , through: :user_grades

  has_many :guardians, through: :user_grades

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :cls

end
```

user_grade.rb

```
class UserGrade < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :admin, optional: true, class_name: 'Admin', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :teacher, optional: true, class_name: 'Teacher', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :student, optional: true, class_name: 'Student', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :guardian, optional: true, class_name: 'Guardian', foreign_key: 'user_id'


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `current_user.grade = Grade.new({})`. Then calling `current_user.save` will save the association and save the new `Grade`.

Comment: Or go through the `user_grade`: `current_user.create_user_grade(...)`.